# Avoiding congestion using Solace if producer sending rate higher than subscriber handling rate

Tags: solace

I have following usage pattern in an application:

1. The publisher sends messages to a topic with rate 5 microseconds per message (i.e. send one message every 5 micros).
2. Consumer subscribes to the topic and handles messages with rate 10 microseconds per message (i.e. it takes 10 micros to complete onReceive callback in JAVA API).
3. The consumer is interested only in the last message published to the topic, so all intermediate not handled messages can be dropped.

Is it possible to avoid the congestion in the queue of unprocessed messages on the consumer side?

I tried to use eliding with delay=0 ([documentation link](https://docs.solace.com/Features/Direct-Messages.htm?Highlight=eliding#Message-Eliding)), however, it doesn’t help if the message already put to the internal queue in the Solace on the consumer side (I refer to com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.XMLMessageQueue).

Setting delay to some specific value works fine, but it doesn't scale well, because this number is dynamic and depends on the number of publishers and consumer performance.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to this would be to create a LVQ (last value queue) which subscribes to the topic. You create a LVQ by setting the queue quota to 0 MB.

Then have your subscribing application consume messages from the LVQ.

In the appliance you should see the nearly same performance as when sending using direct messages as it will never hit the spool.

Comment: If a consumer creates a flow to LVQ, and publisher starts sending with the rate higher than the consumer can handle messages, then the consumer will get all messages anyway from the flow to LVQ, and it means the consumer is busy with handling growing queue of outdated messages. To drop all intermediate messages, the application needs to disconnect and connect again. Is it the way to go, or am I not using LVQ properly? Can share code if needed.

Comment: I would expect setting the AD window size to 1 in your client would mean that you get the next value from the Q when you finished processing the last one. But there's only every 1 message on the queue. Note I haven't tried this out myself.